# Adding a dict if the query set is empty

Tags: django, django-models

I need to check if the Django query has values if not I need to append  a dict to the query set for validation purpose. So, I don't want to create a entry in the database.

Obviously, since I can't append to the queryset(Attribute Error) is there any other way to add this?

```
listing = Listing.objects.values()
if len(listing) < 1:
    listing.append({
        'address': 'some string',
        'range': 'some other string'
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to manually create a list when the queryset is empty, that's rather easy

```
listing = Listing.objects.values()
if len(listing) < 1:
    listing = [{
        'address': 'some string',
        'range': 'some other string'
    }]
```

if you want to append something regardless of whether the queryset is empty or not:

```
listing = list(Listing.objects.values())
listing.append({
        'address': 'some string',
        'range': 'some other string'
    })
```

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

```
listing = Listing.objects.all()
if not listing:
    listing = []
    listing.append({
        'address': 'some string',
        'range': 'some other string'
    })
```

Comment: In this way, if I have data in `listing.objects.all` I would be a list and when I do this with in the validation code `for dict in Listing.objects.values('address'):
        value.text = dict['address']/ value.text = dict['range'] ` would throw error when I access them . :(

Comment: so then check isinstance(your_object, list) -> if true use `for item in listing`

then you can make `item.get('your_field')`

Answer (score 0):

```
listing = Listing.objects.values()
if not listing.exists():
    listing = [{
        'address': 'some string',
        'range': 'some other string'
    }]
```